# Retrieving users from Azure AD with Powershell and a csv file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-3.0

I want to get users from azure stored in a csv file

This is what i have tried so far but i've got no results and yet no errors

```
Connect-AzureAD
$usercsv= Import-Csv -Path C:\Victor\csv.csv -Delimiter "," | Select-Object userPrincipalName
if ($usercsv){
    foreach($user in $usercsv){
        try{
            Get-AzureADUser -All $True | Where-Object {$_.userPrincipalName -like $user}
            return;
            }
        catch { 
            Write-Output "error"
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
            }
    }

}
else{
"No user data stored"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the CSV actually has `UserPrincipalNames` this should give you at least some expected results:

```
Connect-AzureAD
$usercsv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Victor\csv.csv #  -Delimiter "," > Is default for this cmdlet
foreach($user in $usercsv)
{
    $upn = $user.UserPrincipalName.Trim()
    $azUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$upn'"

    if(-not $azUser)
    {
        Write-Warning "$upn could not be found in AzureAD"
        continue
    }

    $azUser
}
```

Comment: I get an error inhere `$azUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$upn'"`

Comment: @victorsionado good to know, yeah, when we use `-Filter` if it can't find the user instead of giving you an error it should not return anything so that was weird. The only way it could be returning an error is if you use a null value like: `Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$null'"`